# Show 3 fields input in one single field

Tags: python, orm, module, field, odoo

I wonder if there is some way to show in one field, a concatenation of 3 other fields, already in the same form.

Like for example:

```
'field_1' : fields.integer('Campo 1'),
 field_2' : fields.integer('Campo 2'),
 field_3' : fields.integer('Campo 3'),
```

Then show the inputs of these 3 fields concatenated in one single field:

```
field_concatenated : fields.related(?)('field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3', 'Name of the field'),
```

I put an '?' sign cause i actually don't know how to achieve this, maybe using a `related` type one? By the way the 3 fields are on the same class-form.

The resulting field could be `readonly`, and show up after the form has been saved.

I hope i've explained myself.

Thanks in advance

```
EDIT
```

The fields can be of the type `integer` and `char`

```
2nd EDIT
```

Actual Example:

```
'empresa' : fields.integer('Empresa'),
'provee' : fields.integer('Proveedor'),
'soli_cant' : fields.integer('Cantidad de Solicitudes'),
'dest' : fields.char('Destino'),
'anho' : fields.integer('Año'),
```

So, after these fields are filled manually, the resulting field have to show me a concatenation of these 4 fields, in a format like `empresa-proveesoli_cant-dest-anho`

Being `provee` and `soli_cant` one after the another, (without the '-') if it can't be possible then that show me the concatenation without separator

Maybe it isn't necessarily declared on the python code, maybe there is some shortcut in the xml view?

Something like `<field name="empresa" "provee" "soli_cant" "dest" "anho" />` idk...

```
3rd EDIT
```

The actual code i'm using right now (Thanks to [Ethan Furman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/208880/ethan-furman)):

The columns:

```
    'empresa' : fields.integer('Empresa'),
    'provee' : fields.integer('Proveedor'),
    'soli_cant' : fields.integer('Cantidad de Solicitudes'),
    'dest' : fields.char('Destino'),
    'anho' : fields.integer('Año'),
```

The function with it's column:

```
def _combinalos(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, args, context=None):
    values = {}
    for id in ids:
        rec = self.browse(cr, uid, [id], context=context)[0]
        values[id] = {}
        values[id][field_name] = '%s %s %s %s %s' %(rec.empresa, rec.provee, rec.soli_cant, rec.dest, rec.anho)
    return values

columns = {
    'nombre' : fields.function(_combinalos, string='Referencia de Pedido', type='char', arg=('empresa','provee','soli_cant', 'dest', 'anho'), method=True),
```

All this on the same `class` of course.

Then i call it from my xml `view` like this:

```
<h1>
   <label string="Request for Quotation " attrs="{'invisible': [('state','not in',('draft','sent'))]}"/>
   <label string="Purchase Order " attrs="{'invisible': [('state','in',('draft','sent'))]}"/>
   <field name="nombre" class="oe_inline" readonly="1" />
</h1>
```

The `label string` is to filter if this is a `Request for Quotation` or a `Purchase Order`

After all this, i do fill the 5 fields of `integer` and `char` type, but still don't get these fields 'concatenated' in one string, or title, just a label saying [object Object], it could be a `label` issue? String name of function in the column maybe?

Comment: Do you have existing code that you could post?

Comment: Actually i don't, but i can write down one ASAP for clarification purposes, i'm gonna edit my question.

Comment: Made the edit, i hope this clarifies my case, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new functional field and combine the three other fields there:

```
def _combine(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, args, context=None):
    values = {}
    for id in ids:
        rec = self.browse(cr, uid, [id], context=context)[0]
        values[id] = {}
        values[id] = '%s %s %s' % (rec.field1, rec.field2, rec.field3)
    return values

_columns = {
    ...
    fields.function(_combine, string='three fields in one!', type='char',
                    arg=('field1','field2','field3'), method=True),
```

Note: untested code

The `_combine` method should be part of the class with the other columns, and the `fields.function` should also be in that class' `_columns`.

Comment: Thank you! But it gives me an error, says "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" the error comes in the last line before the 'return' statement, i used 5 fields, being 4 integers, and 1 char, could be this the issue?

Comment: @KristianKoci: I forgot a `%` sign on that line.  Fixed.

Comment: Awesome! But it shows only [object Object] i filled the fields, but it doesn't shows me the data on these fields, just [object Object]

Comment: Thank you, but if i understand you well, then it is already in the same class, all of: integer, char, and function, including function itself (_combine) are on the same class :(, and yes all in the same column.

Comment: I mean, function is in the same class as all the fields, and function field is in the same _column as the other fields.

Comment: @KristianKoci: Figured it out -- the code I had adapted from was setting several fields at once.  If only one field is being returned, the `values[id][field_name]` should just be `values[id]`.  Sorry.  :/

Comment: Ohhh hahaha lol, don't worry, thank you sooo much for your help, really, well, let me try this way and i'll see :), i'm implementing your filter answer too, thank you!

Comment: Still got this object Object, i don't know, there must be something on the function, can't figure it out, i'm sorry :(

Comment: Done! The problem was the 'string='' name, now it works perfectly! Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!

Comment: Solved, added all 'char' fields, instead of 'integer' :), thank you again!